# PHP: How to find difference of 2D arrays?

Tags: php, arrays

I have two multidimensional arrays.. with same data... what happens is.. values in one array may be changing internally in one multidimensional array.. here is my array...

```
$previousA = array();
$previousA["t"] = array("twitter","picasa");
$previousA["d"] = array("youtube","gmail");


$freshA = array();
$freshA["t"] = array("twitter","picasa","gmail");
$freshA["d"] = array("youtube");
```

at any time total values will be four "twitter","picasa","youtube","gmail" which may inter change from $`previousA["t"]` <=> `$previousA["d"]` now i want to know which values change from `$previousA["t"]` to $`previousA["d"]` comparing with $freshA

Comment: What output are you expecting in your example given ?

Comment: i want to know that gmail is moved from ["d"] => ["t"] from previousA

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of array difference function [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) as:

```
$from_d_to_t = array_diff($freshA["t"],$previousA["t"]);
$from_t_to_d = array_diff($freshA["d"],$previousA["d"]);

if($from_d_to_t) {
        echo "Elements moved from d to t are ".implode(',',$from_d_to_t)."\n";
}
if($from_t_to_d) {
        echo "Elements moved from t to d are ".implode(',',$from_t_to_d)."\n";
}
```

[**Working code**](http://www.ideone.com/eDuwP)

Answer (score 0):

Thats simple all you need to do is **loop through your multi-dimension** array(which i assume is of order 2) and use the function **[array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)** to compare the sub arrays. This function gives difference between two array i.e the extra records in array

Answer (score 0):

If your elements have to be either in `t` or `d` then you really only need to keep track of one of `t` or `d`.

```
ex)
$previousT = array('twitter', 'picasa');
$currentT = array('picasa', 'gmail');

then 

$d_to_t = array_diff($currentT, $previousT);  // 'gmail'
$t_to_d = array_diff($previousT, $currentT);  // 'twitter'
```